# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘cv2’

Tags: python, opencv, streamlit

I am getting this error when trying to deploy my streamlit app. It runs perfectly when I execute it through vscode. How to fix it?

```
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 475, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)File "/app/face-emotion-recognition/streamlit_app.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
```

Comment: Run `pip install cv2` first!

Comment: add a `requirements.txt` and add `opencv-python` there. see docs: https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/app-dependencies#add-python-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because you've only installed the `cv2` module in VSCode! Try installing it in the platform you're currently using.